# Confirm my attempt at converting Crystal reports selection criteria to Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports

I have to create selection criteria for an Oracle SQL query based on a snippet from Crystal Reports.

I have no experience with Crystal reports so I have been trying to figure it out searching the web, but seem to be just wasting my time - Could not find anything helpful for this kind of task on the web.

This is the selection criteria that was provided:

```
{MATL_USED_VW.MAT_ID} = {?Material ID} and 
{@Use Date} in {?Previous Use} 
      //@UseDate = Date({MATERIAL_ACTIVITIES.MA_END})
```

The column data types are all date columns except for the numeric MAT_ID column

I think this would equate to the following:

```
where matl_used_vw.mat_id = :Material_id
  and use_date in (:previous_use, :usedate)
```

This is just a swag based on assumptions.

Here's my assumptions on the symbols:

? - probably is a parameter or prompt for input

@ -  has something to do with formulas

// - is continuation of previous line

{} - encloses an object (text, date number  or whatever)

I'm not sure of anything here, it's all just a guess.

If anyone could shed some light on this, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: How about running it and see?

Comment: I can use the where clause and I get rows back that look sensible to me, but the guy who provided the crystal reports code won't be back in office for another 10 days, so I can't confirm if it's the results he is expecting.

Comment: I would rather get plain English describing what results are expected than some code snippet.  Even if the code they give has the correct syntax, a lot of times what is provided does not do what they think it will do, so you end up starting from scratch anyway. expected

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help on this!

Here's the answer in case some other schmuck unfamiliar with Crystal reports needs a similar answer:

@ is a Formula.  In this case, to convert text to date.

? is a Parameter  In this case it represents a range

// is a remark.  Same as # or ‘ in other languages.

{} - encloses an object (text, date number or whatever)